# How to tell if a path is from an Active Directory redirected folder?

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have `My Documents` folder [redirected](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786749%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to some location on the server for a specific Active Directory user:

[image]

That folder is also assigned a drive letter for that user:

[image]

If I have an arbitrary path, say `"R:\Documents\Some folder\Document1"`, how can I tell that it refers to a redirected location?

Answer (score 1):

The only somewhat suitable way that I found so far is to call [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check for `DRIVE_REMOTE`. If anyone finds a better way, please post it here.